# What do Allowed and Forbidden transitions tell us about the properties of a photon?

Tags: photons, atomic-excitation

What do Allowed and Forbidden transitions tell us about the properties of a photon?

Allowed transitions have the change in angular momentum $\ell=1$, all the others are forbidden. But what does it tell us?

Answer (score 2):

Allowed and forbidden transitions in any interaction depend on the properties of both parts entering the interaction.

In the case of atomic transitions it is conservation of energy and quantum numbers in the reaction that are involved when assigning the "allowed" label.

If we did not know that [the photon has intrinsic spin 1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) we would deduce it from the angular momenta of allowed and forbidden energy states of the atom under observation: It was observed that in order for a transition to be possible/allowed, the photon (exciting  or) decaying from that energy level had to transition to a lower level where the difference in angular momentum is 1. Thus it has to have spin one and energy the energy difference.